# ERROR : The remote name could not be resolved: 'graph.facebook.com' Could not get access token

Tags: facebook, token

the problem is each two hours the application get this error and after two hours the application will work
am new to facebook application any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a short term token see [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) you need to extend it to a long-term token which should then last about 60 days.

Comment: thanks man really you saved me because i was online

Comment: occurs again @norlesh

Comment: You will need to edit your question or start a new one to include some code in your question then so people can understand exactly what your doing and help find a solution.